# How to make relative layout GONE inside ViewFlipper on condition

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, viewflipper

I have an XML, in that XML i have a RelativeLayout say R1, now inside R1 i have one ViewFlipper and inside ViewFlipper i have 7 relative layouts, Everything works fine if i load all seven on my UI, but on condition i want only 3 relative layout (inside ViewFlipper) to be shown on the UI. Can anyone help me to make rest 4 relative layouts to be View.GONE.
I tried setting them

```
            if(X==Y){
            findViewById(R.id.relativeA).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.relativeB).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.relativeC).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.relativeD).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

but this is not working. I set this in onCreate under the require condition, but this view gets GONE only when the activity is launched and when i Fling here and there with the finger, all layouts come on the UI.

Now the only solution I am left is to create another XML with required relativelayouts, but the problem is my XML is quite heavy and i dont wanna use this last option. Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use `viewFlipper.removeViewAt(index)` providing the index (position) of the View that you want to remove.

OR

You can use `viewFlipper.removeView(viewFlipper.findViewById(ID_OF_RELATIVE_LAYOUT_TO_REMOVE))`

There is also a helper method called

`removeViews(int start, int count)` which removes several Views in one go.

For more information, you could look into the [ViewGroup - Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Comment: @c05mic  Can you explain why you recommend removing a View rather than hiding it?  Is is more stable or uses less memory to complete the method pass?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the view, try removing the unwanted views like

```
viewfliper.removeViewAt(relativeA POSITION);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you recommend removing a View rather than hiding it?  Is is more stable or uses less memory to complete the method pass?